# What do you call the person who goes through the minutes after a meeting and checks that everything is correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

At any formal meeting, you appoint a secretary to takes the minutes, and another person to go through the minutes after the meeting and check that everything is correct, right? Now I'm wondering what you call this other person? I was thinking perhaps "attestant" (because they attest that the minutes are correct), but I haven't been able to find any support for this in dictionaries or when I google it.

Note that this is not a duplicate of the post "What is the person who takes minutes in a meeting called?" since I'm asking about a **different** role, which is not discussed at all in that post. Thing is, the role discussed in the other post is ”the minute-taker”, which has an exact match in my language/culture. In my culture, the minute-taker role is, however, separate from the role I’m asking about in this post; that is, we have **both** a minute-taker **and** a role called ”justerare” (i.e. a person whose sole responsibility is to proofread the minutes and sign off on them). Apparently, this latter role doesn’t exist in an English meeting context; instead, the duty of this role is taken over by other roles (among them the minute-taker), but this is not clear from (or even discussed in) the suggested duplicate. Consequently, I think the present post serves its own purpose :)

Comment: Not any meeting I've been at (and I've been at a few...) The minutes are presented at the subsequent meeting, and the first order of business is the correctness of the minutes from the previous meeting.  "Attestant" is someone who attests to the authenticity of a document like a contract or a passport

Comment: Checking Roberts rules,  there are only three officers mentioned: chair, secretary and treasurer. And the minutes have to be checked and assented to by everyone present at the meeting.  The role you describe is not part of a *formal* meeting (though informal meetings might have their own rules)

Comment: @JamesK Huh! No wonder I couldn't find a word for it then! Interesting to see that these things apparently differ from one country to another – I would've thought the roles at a formal meeting would be roughly the same in all countries. Oh well. Do you have any suggestions as to what word I could use to refer to a person like this though, that people would understand even though you don't have this in English-speaking countries?

Comment: [Dupe?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147341/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-checks-if-everything-is-all-right)

Comment: I'd probably say "a person who checks the minutes"

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73113/what-is-the-person-who-takes-minutes-in-a-meeting-called

Comment: I would note that in the SE answer I linked to above, mention is made of a 'Company Secretary' role. There may be a regional usage difference. In the UK this role is a senior management position, and the holder may well be a qualified specialist lawyer, not a glorified typist or stenographer.

Comment: In the UK, the person who takes the minutes also checks them and agrees with the attendees and chair that they are accurate. There is no 'other person' who does these things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the person who takes minutes in a meeting called?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73113/what-is-the-person-who-takes-minutes-in-a-meeting-called)

Comment: Boards of directors have officers. In general, the officers are: president, vice-president, treasurer and secretary. The secretary is in charge of the final form of the minutes even if that secretary's assistant makes the changes or edits it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137236/discussion-on-question-by-lillatanten-what-do-you-call-the-person-who-goes-throu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about elsewhere, but here in the UK, at a meeting, someone will be designated to be the **minute taker** (can be hyphenated as 'minute-taker'). This may be someone who is also a participant in their own right, or someone who takes no part, but is present as a kind of secretary, to listen and record.

> The basic tasks for the minute taker are:
>
> Taking rough notes that accurately reflect the decisions and
> discussion that took place during the meeting.
>
> Writing up these notes in an agreed format (whether electronically or
> in hard copy) so that information can be easily discerned and
> communications are clear, thus avoiding any confusion.
> Responsibilities and ownership must be clearly indicated within the
> minutes.
>
> Copying and distributing the minutes to all relevant people as
> detailed in the Participants section.
>
> Ensuring that a copy is filed appropriately, keeping all minutes
> together in a file for future reference.

[Responsibilities of the Minute Taker](http://www.free-management-ebooks.com/faqmt/minutes-03.htm)

Regarding the word 'attestant',  I have never, ever, heard of an 'attestant' in a UK/British business meeting context, formal or otherwise. It may be a [false friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) - in Germanic languages, e.g. Swedish, German, Danish, Norwegian, Dutch, I think it is a legal word for a person who attests to the genuineness of a document or signature by adding their own signature. In British English legal language, we would use 'witness' for that, in connection with e.g. a will, passport application, etc. However this is a narrow legal meaning, not in connection with business meetings.

Comment: Thank you! Could you just add that there is no such thing as a separate "attestant" in meetings in an English context? That way your answer will be spot on, and I can check it as the answer that solved my problem :)

Comment: @Lillatanten - I have done that.

Comment: @Lillatanten The person on a board of directors in charge of the minutes, ultimately, is the secretary. That is the same thing in the UK and in NA. However, that secretary may have an assistant make the actual changes.

Comment: I think–not sure mind you–that *notary* fits the description. Excessive perhaps, but maybe in certain government departments that person's duties  would also include checking the minutes and placing his/her signature to authenticate the papers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notary

Comment: @Mari-LouA - must be an American term.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Believe me, American and British boards have zero do with notaries. PLEASE. :) Signature authentication is not a "thing" with regard to board minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a **proofreader**. This may not be the official title of the person (especially in a small company where everyone [wears many hats](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wear%20many%20hats)), but it can be. For example, see this old job description  for a Nevada Senate [Proofreader](https://hr.nv.gov/uploadedFiles/hrnvgov/Content/Services/Recruitment/Proofreader08142014.pdf):

> The Proofreader performs a comprehensive review of Senate Committee minute reports for order and understanding, legislative intent, accuracy of information, sentence structure, grammar, punctuation and spelling. Generally, minute reports will be reviewed at least three times, each time by a different proofreader.

Of course, *proofreader* is a generic word that also refers to people who check other written documents, anything from social media posts to novels to scientific articles.